# Get distinct rows using inner join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-6

I have this statement using Rails 3.2:

```
Event.joins(:picks).where(picks: {result: nil,created_at: 5.days.ago..Time.now,league_id: 1})
```

It returns what I want but with many duplicate Events.

How can I get just the unique Events?

I tried adding .distinct to the end but it returns

```
#<Arel::Nodes::Distinct:0x007fc13e587800>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Event
  .joins(:picks)
  .where(picks: {result: nil, created_at: 5.days.ago..Time.now, league_id: 1})
  .group("events.id")
```

Comment: Why does it return a hash when I put `.size` on the end of what you gave me?

Comment: `Event.joins(:picks).where(picks: {result: nil,created_at: 5.days.ago..Time.now,league_id: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}).group('events.id').each do |event|` will iterate over the expected Events. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
event_id_query = Pick.where(result: nil,created_at: 5.days.ago..Time.now,league_id: 1).select(:event_id)
Event.where(id: event_id_query)
```

This will create subquery and will return only distinct events from database.